# CSS animation on ngOnDestroy or DOM removal

Tags: angular, typescript, css-animations

I'm using Angular 7 and I want to run some CSS animation on the host element of a component when that element is removed from the DOM - the component is destroyed.

- if I want to do this on `ngOnDestroy` method, the host element is already removed from DOM.
- if I want to use `MutationObserver` listening for removed elements in the parent component then I have the same problem the element is already removed from DOM.

What other options I have and what is the best way to do this? I also mention that I don't want to use jquery or any of its plugins.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the luxury of rethinking the problem, you could do something like that with Angular Animations' `void` state and `*ngIf`.

Import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` into your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserAnimationsModule ]
})
```

The parent component containing your to-be-destroyed component can implement the `void` state animation and apply it to the child component with `*ngIf`. eg:

```
@Component({

  animations: [
    trigger('animateDestroy', [
      state('void', style({ opacity: '0' })),
      transition('* => void', animate('500ms ease'))
    ])
  ],

  template: `
    <component-to-destroy *ngIf="someBoolean" @animateDestroy>
    </component-to-destroy>
  `

})
export class ParentComponent {
  someBoolean = true;
}
```

If you change `someBoolean` to `false`, Angular will remove the component from the DOM because of the `*ngIf`. But before that, the `animateDestroy` trigger with the `* => void` tells Angular to animate out before removing the element from the DOM.

[Some reading about Angular Animations and the `void` state on the docs.](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#void-state)

It's not CSS, but it can result in the same effect CSS provides. It lets the template handle the "destroyed-or-not" state of your component with a boolean instead of jumping through programmatic hoops inside the class.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service i think.
Check the last part of [this page](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

You would have to create an observable in the service and call it in the onDestroy of your component.
Then subscribe to this event in your parent.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit, with an explanation? Answers just posting a link are usually downvoted and removed on Stackoverflow